# How to save workspace in r from multiple rstudio windows?

Tags: save, rstudio, workspace

I run programming in multiple rstudio windows. I save work in each window before close them one by one. When I start a new rstudio window, in the workspace only the files in the latest closed window are saved and shown. I cannot see the files in the previously closed windows.

So I have to run them in one single window?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of the instances are running in the same working directory (you can check using the getwd() command)  then all workspaces (.RData file) will save to the same path overwriting each other.